# Running Background Loop while Taking in Input (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, loops

I am currently working on developing a simple game, but I am getting quite stumped with one of the core mechanics. I want to be able to run a background loop that updates information (such as currency, location, etc.) every second or so. However, I want the user to be able to input actions at any moment without interrupting the loop. These actions will then change the way the background loop is updating info. My most recent attempt at this was to have two threads running simultaneously. One which will run the background clock and one which will constantly be open to input and react appropriately. However, I found it difficult for the input thread to affect the background thread. They were both just running in there own little world.

Any ideas as to how to approach this issue? Is multi-threading the right approach? Any help would be appreciated :). I can show some of my code if need be.

Comment: Have you implemented any sort of a thread-safe queue or similar structure?  The input would go into the queue, and the other thread(s) would just check if input is in the queue.

Comment: On most systems, you will find it easier to use separate terminal (i.e. a terminal emulator) for input and output.  On Linux, type tty in a terminal and a typical response will be "/dev/pts/0" or "/dev/pts/17".   Use one for your "background loop", the other for all other user i/o (via fstream)

Answer (score 1):

Simple method: Update the information right after user makes any changes if the update procedure is not taking too much time. This way you don't need multi-threading. Basic idea, if there is a changes then update.

Advance method: You will have 2 thread. First thread receives the action from the user, queue it. The second thread read the action in the queue and update information according to the action.
Looking like this: 
INPUT thread -> [up,down,...,left,right,up] -> UPDATE thread

You can easily google the solution because this type of problem is pretty 'classic'.

Answer (score 1):

The are a lot of ways to share information between threads.  This is just an example.  You can also global scope or IPC messaging.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

typedef struct program_data_t {
    program_data_t() : counter(0) { }

    int counter;
    boost::mutex mutex;
} program_data_t;

void update_loop(program_data_t* pd) {
    while(1) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(milliseconds(50));

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(pd->mutex);

        pd->counter++;
    }
}

void print_loop(program_data_t* pd) {
    while(1) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(seconds(1));

        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(pd->mutex);

        cout << pd->counter << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    program_data_t pd;

    boost::thread update_thread(boost::bind(update_loop, &pd));
    boost::thread print_thread(boost::bind(print_loop, &pd));

    update_thread.join();
    print_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```